# what is the best way to change users ids into object kohana ORM

Tags: kohana, kohana-3, kohana-orm

noob's problem:
I need to select specific ids from DB query called user_id. my result from DB::select is:

```
$query=DB::select...
$ids=$query->as_object()-execute();
$players=ORM::factory('User'->select()->where('id', 'in', array($this->to_array($ids)));
```

and method to_array:

```
private function to_array($obj)
{
    $arr=array();
    foreach($obj as $o)
    {
        array_push($arr, $o->user_id);
    }
    return $arr;
}
```

is better solution in Kohana 3.3 ORM to create container of User from specified ids?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to have separate queries as ORM extends the Database class:

```
$users = ORM::factory('User')
    ->where('your_filter', '=', $whatever_value)
    ->find_all();
```

Also, `Database_Result` comes with its own 'to_array' function: `as_array` e.g.

```
// Will generate an array with e.g. array(15 => 'Peter', 27 => 'Meg');
$users->as_array('id', 'name');

// Will generate a 'standard' array with e.g. array(0 => 'Peter', 1 => 'Meg')
$users->as_array(NULL, 'name');

// Will convert the results into an array e.g. array(0 => Model_User, 2 => Model_User)
$users->as_array();
```

So if for some reason you really need to use an array of Ids from a resultset:

```
$users = ORM::factory('User')
    ->where('id', 'IN', $results->as_array('id', 'id'))
    ->find_all();
```

It really pays off to study ORM a bit before building stuff, just checking out the user guide is not enough; look at the [api browser](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide-api/ORM)

Comment: well its not the exactly answer for my question because I cant generate users as array like in your example, but thanks for help I've build difference querie.

Comment: What do you mean `I cant generate users as array like in your example`?

Comment: I updated the answer (see third `as_array` example) to 'maybe' cover your question